# Get the remainder of SUBSTRING_INDEX

Tags: mysql, substring

I have a problem regarding `SUBSTRING_INDEX`.

[image: SQL Table]

As the image shows, I can get the city by

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(location,'-',1)) FROM my_table
```

However for the state_country column, I need the value which is after the '-'.

Is there a way to get that value and add it to the state_country column?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(location,'-',1)  as city 
       ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(location,'-',-1) as state_country

FROM    my_table
```

Comment: Not universally accurate, particularly if more than one such delimiter appears in the string.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, can we assume that the last `-` is always a delimiter and not a part of the last name?

Comment: It depends on the data.  I would argue that the primary flaw here is not with your solution, it is with the schemata -- metro + "-" + state is not an atomic value and therefore should not be stored together in one column because doing so violates [1NF](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).  A second problem is that sometimes the `-` has spaces around it in the example data, so a more complete and data-dependent solution is needed.

Comment: I would be inclined to use `TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(location,'-',-1))` for the state and something more hideous but more precise, like `TRIM(LEFT(location, (CHAR_LENGTH(location) - CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(location,'-',-1)) - 1)))` for the city... that is, find the length of the untrimmed state value, subtract that value and 1 more for the delimiter from the length of the entire string as *n*, take the leftmost *n* characters from the column, then trim it, to get the city.  Untidy data leads to untidy solutions.

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this, I did the following:

Sample data table.

```
CREATE TABLE city_state
(
  location VARCHAR(100),
  city VARCHAR(100)
);
```

Sample data.

```
INSERT INTO city_state VALUES ('Minneapolis - Minnesota', 'Minneapolis'); -- note, space between hyphen and Minnesota
INSERT INTO city_state VALUES ('Orange County - CA', 'Orange County');
INSERT INTO city_state VALUES ('Denver - Colorado', 'Denver');
INSERT INTO city_state VALUES ('Dowingtown-Pennsylvania', 'Downingtown');  -- note, no space between "Downington" and "Pennsylvania" - also,
INSERT INTO city_state VALUES ('Manhattan-New York', 'Manhattan');
INSERT INTO city_state VALUES ('Ventura-California', 'Ventura');
INSERT INTO city_state VALUES ('Winston-Salem-North Carolina', 'Winston-Salem');  -- note, compound place name, i.e. Winston-Salem
```

For the Winston-Salem example, check [here](http://funtrivia.com/askft/Question114712.html)!

As pointed out by @Dudu Markovitz, you have to select from the **last** hyphen.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( location, '-', -1) FROM city_state;
```

**But**, there are also fields with spaces between the hyphen and those without, so a more complete answer would be:

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX( location, '-', -1)) FROM city_state;

Minnesota
CA
Colorado
Pennsylvania
New York
California
North Carolina
```

Note, no spaces preceding (or following) the location name.

Comment: can we assume that the last - is always a delimiter and not a part of the last name?